# Discord bot create a "channel" variable

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm discovering the python discord bot module and it's a very good exercise to practice my python. 
So using the discord module I try to create a channel and put it in a variable at the same time (I don't want to search for the channel in the list after creation)

here is the code I am trying to execute :

```
import discord  
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?")

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    server = client.get_server(os.environ['DISCORD_SERVER_ID]) 
    cCurrent = client.create_channel(server, str("%s 0" %(pokeName)))
[...]
    await client.send_message(cCurrent, embed=raid.embed())
```

When I execute this code, I have the error  :

```
in send_message
    [...]
 in _resolve_destination
    raise InvalidArgument(fmt.format(destination))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received generator
```

So I imagine that the `client.create_channel` has not been executed, is this normal using python ?

how can I create the new channel object in the client and in the variable at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Client.create_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_channel) is a coroutine, which means you must use the `await` syntax (or `yield from` in Python 3.4) to get its value:

```
cCurrent = await client.create_channel(server, str("%s 0" %(pokeName)))
```